# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'base_prefix' при получении EXE файла из Python 2.7 при помощи cxFreeze 5.0.2

Tags: python-2.7

Windows 7 64-bit pyton 2.7 cxfreze 5.0.2

Программа:

```
"""
Created on Tue Feb 14 16:41:40 2017
@author: George
"""
# coding: utf8
import sys
base_prefix = getattr(sys, 'base_prefix', getattr(sys, 'real_prefix', sys.prefix))

from theano import function, config, shared, tensor
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], tensor.exp(x).transfer(None))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (numpy.asarray(r),))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, tensor.Elemwise) and
              ('Gpu' not in type(x.op).__name__)
              for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

Comment: Неужели  только у меня такая ошибка. Кто нибудь победил ее ?!

Comment: Кто нибудь может объяснить что такое base_prefix зачем он нужен и как его задать чтобы не было ошибки при получении exe файла

Answer (score 0):

1.Победил ошибку:AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'base_prefix'.
Изменил файл hook.py
c:\Users\George\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py
dll_path = os.path.join ( getattr (sys, " real_prefix " , sys.prefix) , " DLLs " , dll_name)       finder.IncludeFiles(dll_path, dll_name)
2. Возникла другая ошибка:
   from . import _methods
ImportError: cannot import name _methods

Правка в программе вставка:
import numpy.core._methods 
import numpy.lib.format 
3. Появилась ошибка
    (builtin and ", though it should be builtin") + ".")
pygments.util.ClassNotFound: Could not find style module 'default', though it sh
ould be builtin.
Пока не победил может кто то уже встречался с такой ошибкой помогите